# Failed to create process

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I wrote `pyinstaller name.py`

Click <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and shows me

```
D:\Python > pyinstaller "name file"
```

failed to create process.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Can't convert .py to .exe?

Comment: Is this the complete error message? If not show it as properly formatted text in the question.